# Percent difference when both negative

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

In an experiment, I was asked to find the percent difference between theoretical and experimental $y$-intercept (which I have). It is known that its formula is 
$$\text{Percent Difference} =\frac{|x_t-x_e|}{\frac{1}{2}\left(x_t+x_e\right)}\cdot100\%$$
But what if both values (in my case) of $x_t,\,x_e$ are negative? Does that mean I need to write negative percentage or just take its absolute?

Comment: Shouldn't the denominator be $\frac{1}{2}(x_t+x_e)$?

Comment: I've never liked using the absolute value in the numerator.  If the measured value is below theoretical, I want my % error to be negative and if the measured value is above theoretical, I want my % error to be positive.  The absolute value function destroys this information.

Comment: In fairness, this is really more a matter of personal preference. Sometimes the actual sign of the error is quite important (i.e. when looking for drift), and sometimes it is relatively unimportant (when the sample population is evenly distributed and you just want to know how off a particular value is).

Answer (score 0):

It should be $\%=\frac{|x_t-x_e|}{\frac{1}{2}\left(x_t+x_e\right)}$. You dont have to worry about negative values as ${|x_t-x_e|}$ will take care of all possible values + or -  Just plug the values as they are and the difference will be correct.

Comment: The denominator will be negative, though.

Comment: Yeah, typo edited. I mean what if $\frac{1}{2}(x_t+x_e) is negative itself whereas |x_t-x_e| is always nonnegative? Is it ok to have negative percent difference?

Comment: It ok as it will tell you that the percentages were negative. The only problem that could arise in this formula is that $(x_t+x_e)$ might become 0.